# VMware Horizon client run error on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, vmware, shared-library

I installed VMware Horizon client on my Fedora 29 machine.
I downloaded the `VMware-Horizon-Client-4.10.0-11053294.x64.bundle` file from [VMware official download page](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=CART19FQ4_LIN64_410&productId=578&rPId=29503).

When I am running it by searching in the system, it's not running. And when I tried running it from CLI by using command `vmware-view` it is showing below error

> /usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view-crtbora: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libpangomm-1.4.so.1: undefined symbol: *ZN4Glib6ObjectC2EOS0*

I tried searching that library in dnf repos, but unable to find any by name.

I tried solution mentioned [here](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2017/12/13/installing-vmware-horizon-client-fedora-27/), but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `vmware-view` command in `/usr/bin` will use the system libraries instead of the ones included with the View Client.

After installation, prepend the Vmware View libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the bin directory in the installation folder to your PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=export PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/view/bin:$PATH
```

The `vmware-view` command will then open the client GUI as it will be the one in `/usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view` and not the one in `/usr/bin`. You can verify this with `which vmware-view`. This will use the View Client binaries and libraries and not the system binaries and libraries. You can add the two export commands to your ~/.bashrc so that it sets them at login.

Comment: I actually installed version 4.8 and it is working fine now. However, I will try your suggestion as well.

Comment: @imvpn22 I did the same at first and found that 4.9 will also work with the system binary and libraries. Afterwards, I was able to get it to work with 4.10 so I used that one for my answer.